# Set Login User header value into principal in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

**Problem:** How can I set currently login user header value from the header into principal. So that I can easily get the principal value in any Spring Boot Microservice.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/scheme")
    public List<Scheme> schemes(@RequestHeader Map<String,String> headers) {
        
        headers.forEach((key,value) -> {
            System.out.println("Header Name: "+key+" Header Value: "+value);
        });   
    }
```

Here, I am getting whole header and print all the header value in the console but I want only login user header value and its role also. These value set into principal So that I can easily access the login user and its role in any microservice Just doing getPrincipal() method or Authentication Interface in Spring Boot.

Comment: Create a @RequestScope bean for your User (header, name, id, role, email etc with getter and setters). Write an interceptor for your Requests where you initialise this bean. Now Autowire this bean anywhere in your micro-service, it will automatically have the logged in user data. you can just call the getter methods to fetch all values in the methods scoped to the request.

Comment: @PranayNailwal But this header coming from the gateway and this header is already contains authentic username or role but I want only fetch username or its role from whole header. How will I initialise bean in an interceptor?